# Is using alcoholic perfume haram?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, perfume

We know that alcohol is polluted in Islam and also we know that some perfumes has alcohol in their mixture, so I want to know if using such perfumes is Haram or not?

Comment: So your question is about perfumes which contain alcohol not perfumes in general. And do you mean alcohol is *prohibited* instead of *polluted*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of perfumes in general is permissible. And the same ruling applies for perfumes which contain alcohol. This has to do with the fact that alcohol is not najs (unclean). The prohibition is on the consumption/drinking of alcohol.

Therefore, so long as the perfumes doesn't contain anything unclean it is permissible to use them. But is impermissible to wear perfume/cologne (for women; not sure about men) in order to attract/excite members of the opposite sex.

> Question: Is Ethanol of the family of alcohol that causes drunkenness? What about using this and other families of alcohol that are synthesized from petroleum and are used in perfume, medicine etc? Are they najis and cannot be used during prayer?
>
> Answer: According to Grand Ayatullah Sistani alcohol is taher (ritually clean) but it is not permissible to drink it. Using perfume and medicines mixed with alcohol is permissible. *[[source]](http://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01123/)*

> Question: Is it permissible for a woman to wear perfume when going out of her home?
>
> Answer: It is permissible for a woman to go out, wearing perfume even if non-mahram men can smell her perfume; in so doing, she should not aim to arouse or attract such men. *[[source]](http://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01149/)*

Comment: Does this stand for after shave as some times i can feel alcohol going through the nose therefore i just block my nostrils, as i have breathed a little would it be Haram? please dont consider this another question as it is highly related! jazak allah kher

Comment: I highly doubt that is the case. Meaning I don't think that it's haram. Plus intention matters in such cases.